# Count all of a column where value is 2 and sum this value with price

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing with Northwind database where I use the `Products` table. I need to count all of the rows where `Category_Id` is 2 and sum the amount with the prices.

Here's the example of a table shortly:

```
Category_ID | Unit Price
 1          | 2,90
 2          | 3,70
 3          | 4,90
 2          | 1,90
 5          | 0,90
 2          | 2,90
```

There are 3 rows where `category_Id` is 2. How to sum this 3 with that rows Unit price?

```
3,70 + 1,90 + 2,90 = 8,50
```

So the answer I need is 8,50 but I have no idea how to get that amount with a SQL query.

Does someone know?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Comment: Or `SUM` and a `WHERE`; both are basic and fundamental parts of the language so seems you would likely be best off reading a few tutorials. I'm sure if you searched "How to Sum in SQL Server" you'd have the answer.

Comment: Hello @JennieKari You should post the code you have already tried and explain how does it fails, for example do you get an error or do you get an incorrect result. By doing this you will help someone to understand better what you need and thus help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the aggregated values for all Ids using

```
Select Categeory_Id, sum([Unit Price]) Total, count(*) Qty
from Products
group by Category_Id
```

or just a specific total such as

```
select sum([Unit Price]) total
from products
where category_Id=2
```

Comment: @JennieKari great news, hopefully that's helped you on your way, if so feel free to accept answer :-))